# Filter lookup field via javascript function v.9 CE?

Tags: javascript, filter, dynamics-crm

Filter lookup field via javascript function. Entity of occurring custom field service by type of service that is an option set field.

I tried to follow the link below, but it didn't work. Then I tried to complement with fecth xml.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/addcustomfilter

```
function filtraservico() {debugger;
    var Tipodeassunto = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("casetypecode").getValue();
    if (Tipodeassunto) {
        //Construir o Fetchxml 
        var viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-E8603FF8E1E4}";
        var viewDisplayName = "Serviço";
        var entityName = "copasa_portfoliodeservico";

        var fetchXml = "<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' output-format='xml-platform' version='1.0'>" +
            "<entity name='copasa_portfoliodeservico'>" +
            "<attribute name='copasa_portfoliodeservicoid'/>" +
            "<attribute name='copasa_name'/>" +
            "<attribute name='createdon'/>" +
            "<order descending='false' attribute='copasa_name'/>" +
            " <filter type='and'>" +
            "<condition attribute='copasa_casetypecode' value='" + Tipodeassunto + "' operator='eq'/>" +
            "</filter>" +
            "</entity>" +
            "</fetch>";
        //Construir o layout da grid de pesquisa (Exibição)
        var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' " + "object='1' " + "jump='copasa_servicosid' " + "select='1' " + "icon='1' " + "preview='0'>" +
            "<row name='result' " + "id = 'copasa_servicosid'>" +
            "<cell name='copasa_name' " + "width='300' />" +
            "<cell name='copasa_casetypecode' " + "width='250' />" +
            "disableSorting='1' />" +
            "</row>" +
            "</grid>";
        //Adicionar a nova visão
        Xrm.Page.getControl("copasa_servicosid").addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);

        addEvent();
    }
}
function addEvent(){
    Xrm.Page.getControl("copasa_servicosid").addPreSearch(addFilter);
}
function addFilter(){
    var Tipodeassunto = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("casetypecode").getValue();
    var customerServiceFilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='copasa_casetypecode' operator='eq' value='1' /></filter>";
    Xrm.Page.getControl("copasa_servicosid").addCustomFilter(customerServiceFilter, "copasa_portfoliodeservico");
}
```

I just want to show the list of services that have the same type of service that the user selected in the instance.

Comment: don't try to create a complete new View with ID,
rather for ex: If you have active accounts view already available for filter just add your filter criteria. Try adding filter criteria as mentioned in Docs. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: must take the id of an existing view and add in the viewId variable?

Comment: If you're in v9.* then `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("casetypecode").getValue()` is deprecated and may not work. You've got a debugger line in there. How far are you getting? Have you verified that `Xrm.Page.getAttribute()` is returning a value - is `Tipodeassunto ` null?

Comment: Sim, ainda esta funcional o Xrm.Page. Verifiquei a nova função do campo.

https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/preview-for-usability-enhancements-to-lookups-in-unified-interface/

Obrigado pelo apoio.